# How to do a update in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm making a shop in symfony and I'm having trouble with my cart.

What i need to do is when i change the Quantity of the product, then when i click on update i want the cart to update it seft and show the right quantity but it always shows the amount form the start (the 1 or the 3)
[image]

the 3 and the 1 above appeared there because i clicked 3 times on the product

[image]

This is my contoller

```
/**
     * @Route("/update/{qtt}", name="update")
     */
    public function updateAction($qtt,Request $req) 
    {

        $session = $req->getSession();

        $panier = $session->get('panier', []);

        if(empty($panier[$qtt])){
            isset($panier[$qtt]);
        }

        dd($qtt);

        $session->set('panier', $panier);

      return $this->redirectToRoute('panier');
    }
```

And this is the Twig

```
{% for item in items %}
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                    
                            <td>{{ item.produit.Nom }}</td>
                            <td>{{ item.produit.Prix}}$</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  value="{{item.quantitee}}" min="0" max="20"/></td>
                            <td>{{item.quantitee * item.produit.Prix}}$</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{path('item_del', {'id': item.produit.id})}}">supprimer</a></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{{path('update', {'qtt': item.quantitee})}}">update</a></td>

        
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are updating the item with the same quantity over and over. You could solve this wit the [FosJSRouting](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) bundle to generate a new URL when you click on the button to fetch the correct quantity before routing to the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not passing product ID for quantity update/delete.

Here is how your code should look:

**Client-Side**

```
<form action="{{path('update_cart')}}" method="post">
    <table>
        {% for item in items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.produit.Nom }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.produit.Prix}}$</td>
                <td><input type=number name="qty[{{item.produit.id}}]" value="{{item.quantitee}}" min="0" max="20"></td>
                <td>{{item.quantitee * item.produit.Prix}}$</td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_id" value="{{item.produit.id}}}">supprimer</button></td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="update_id" value="{{item.produit.id}}}">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

**Server-Side**

```
/**
 * @Route("/update_cart}", name="update_cart")
 */
public function updateCart(Request $req)
    {
        $session = $req->getSession();

        $product_qty_list = $req->request->get('qty');

        $product_update_id = $req->request->get('update_id');
        $product_delete_id = $req->request->get('delete_id');

        $panier = $session->get('panier', []);

        if ($product_delete_id !== null) {
            // delete item

            unset($panier[$product_delete_id]);
        } else {
            // update item

            $qty = $product_qty_list[$product_update_id];

            if ($qty > 0)
                $panier[$product_update_id] = $qty;
            else
                unset($panier[$product_update_id]);
        }

        $session->set('panier', $panier);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('panier');
    }
```

As you can see I have wrapped a table with a form, that has an action to `update_cart` route.

Every button has its own name and value. For example:

- Delete button has the name `delete_id` and the value of product ID
- Update button has the name `update_id` and the value of product ID

This will help identify what action you are trying to do with the product.

And of course, every quantity input has a key in its name (as an array), this is achieved using `[]` after the name. For example:

- If your input is `<input type=number name="qty[33]" value="12">` and you hit `Update` button, then you will update quantity to 12 for product with ID 33

P.S. You should change your title to `How to update item quantity in shopping cart - Symfony PHP`

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually set the quantity on the `Cart` array.

The `isset` method you are using on `$panier['qtt']` only checks whether the key exsists and there is any value. You need to actually set the value by `$panier['qtt'] = $qtt;`.

What is more, you are using the generated url to access the controller, which only uses the first version of quantity, and it does not change after you change the input. I would suggest using Symfony forms here if possible - using POST to pass the data is the preferred way over passing data in the URL. If not possible - modify the link using javascript after editing the input.

I would also suggest creating a `Cart` class instead of using arrays if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `Update` button HTML code is static. You should either add some Javascript code to update it, or add an HTML form to post data from your `Quantity` input(s).

Here you render a static URL for the update action with the quantity it had on page rendering:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{path('update', {'qtt': item.quantitee})}}">update</a>
```

I would suggest you learn some basics about HTML forms and how to work with forms in PHP.

Comment: This is not the problem. OP is using symfony but is update the item with the same quantity

Comment: What exactly wrong with my answer? How would you suggest sending an HTML input value without forms or JavaScript?

Comment: As I said, OP is using Symfony. His set-up is to perform a `GET` to his existing controller to trigger the function `updateAction`. After this action is executed, the controller will redirect the user to the shoppingcart. That is why no form is needed to be submitted. OP is just failing in passing the new quantity of the item, retrieving this new quantity in his controller and updating the cart (which lives in a session)

Comment: So how would you suggest passing the new value without forms or JavaScript from the HTML input field? That is exactly what I mentioned and what the author has asked. He has asked how to update the qty with a value from the input fields. He needs to use either forms or JavaScript to modify the link he is using to submit quantity. There are a lot of ways to do that, do you suggest to describe all of them instead of pointing roots of the problem?

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558412/how-to-do-a-update-in-php/66558675?noredirect=1#comment117665091_66558412)

Comment: The suggested bundle is using JavaScript under the hood.

Comment: Well ofcourse, but that library is able to connect with Symfony. See as how I posted that as an comment as well and not as an answer? How does this answer help op solve his problem in any way? To be frank this should be a comment as well, not an answer